# Unity-How to stop a moving object when the Camera sees it

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, renderer, gameobject

This is just a simple thing I want to do. I have my cube gameobject rotating and I want to make it so when the camera sees the cube, it stops rotating. If you could steer me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it. thank you

```
public class cubeMove : MonoBehaviour, MoveObject
{
public Renderer rend;

    public void Update () {

    rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    stopWhenSeen();      
}
public void move()
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime);
}
public void stopWhenSeen()
{
    if (rend.enabled == false)
    {
        move();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Implement the [`OnBecameVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html) and [`OnBecameInvisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) MonoBehaviour's message :

```
private visible = false ;

// OnBecameVisible is called when the renderer became visible by any camera. INCLUDING YOUR EDITOR CAMERA
void OnBecameVisible()
{
    visible = true ;
}

// OnBecameInvisible is called when the renderer is no longer visible by any camera. INCLUDING YOUR EDITOR CAMERA
void OnBecameInvisible()
{
    visible = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if( !visible )
        move() ;
}

public void move()
{
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(15, 30, 45) * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: would seen be a boolean value and is onBecameInvisible is predetermined function?

Comment: Yes to both questions..

You may find the documentation for OnBecameVisible() in the link below.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameVisible.html

Comment: I'm doing it, but it seems like it stops once I see it, but doesn't keep moving when I look away.

Comment: In fact, because your editor camera is rendering your object, `OnBecameInvisible` is never called.

Comment: I realised I made a typo in `OnBecameInvisible`, make sure the `v` is in lower-case.

Comment: I thought of something. the onbecamevisible function applies to the scene camera as well as the main camera. How would I make it so it only applies to the main camera?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

You could try the .isVisible bool in your update method.

Here is a thread with other suggestions:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html

Comment: I'm trying to do the onbecamevisible and onbecameinvisible, then in update, if public bool seen is true, then move, but the cube only moves for a second before stopping.

Comment: Did you check what the 'seen' bool says?

Does it switch as intended between true and false?

Comment: Seen is initialized as false, onbecameinvisible has seen be false, onbecamevisible has seen be true, and if !seen, then move().

Comment: Try remove the * Time.deltaTime part of your calculation, I suspect it might interfere in this case, then re-attempt to see if the rotation begins again.

I'm guessing something is misbehaving inside your move script.

Comment: then how I keep the cube rotating?

Comment: My bad, according to this example it should work with that approach.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Is the object your script is on, the same object as the one you are trying to rotate?

Also, does your script inherit from MonoBehaviour?

Comment: Just noticed that MonoBehaviour is in front of the MoveObject inheritance.

What goes on inside the MoveObject inheritance?

Comment: I thought of something. the onbecamevisible function applies to the scene camera as well as the main camera. How would I make it so it only applies to the main camera?

Comment: Using this method you should be able to, see the link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.OnWillRenderObject.html